# Integer passed into function as 8 but then value inside function is -439854520

Tags: c++, integer

Inside of main I have the following block which calls pad_string.
For some strange reason, inside of pad_string, 'total' has the value -439854520. I am wondering why this is?.

UPDATE: Added full definition and .cpp file

```
  int x = 8;
  cout << x << endl; 
  std::string s("001");
  pad_string(s,x);
```

definition

```
#ifndef BITS_HPP
#define BITS_HPP


//#: Converts a character into its binary representation
//as a string
std::string chr_to_binary(char c);


//@: x is desired length of string
//#: make a zero string of size x
std::string make_zero_string(int x);

//@:s is the string to be padded
//@:total is the desired total length of str
//#:pads s with as many zeros as neccessary so
//that s's total lenth equal total<D-r>
std::string pad_string(std::string s,int total);
```

implementation

```
std::string chr_to_binary(char c)
{
    std::bitset<8> bset(c);
    return bset.to_string();
}

std::string make_zero_string(int x){
    std::string s;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x; ++i){
        s.push_back('0');
        break;
    }
    return s;
}

//@:s is the string to be padded
//@:total is the desired total length of str
//#:pads s with as many zeros as neccessary so
//that s's total lenth equal total.
//Padding occurs to left of s
void pad_string(std::string s,int total)
{
    std::cout << (total) << std::endl;
    int length = s.length();
    std::cout << total << std::endl;
    std::cout << length << std::endl;
    if (length < total){
        int diff = total - length;
        std::cout << diff << std::endl;
        std::string zerostr = make_zero_string(diff);
        zerostr = zerostr + s;
        s = zerostr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wherever possible, don't mutate the things passed to a function - make the function return the mutated value via  a return statement.

Comment: Unable to reproduce: https://ideone.com/djicNM This means I'm doing something differently from what you are doing. May we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: The function prototype has a return type of `std::string` but the implementation returns `void`. Make up your mind. Edit: now you've changed the prototype to take a `std::string` by value but the implementation takes it by reference. Does this compile?

Comment: @Blastfurnace Indeed it does, I went ahead and fixed that so it returns a string now. Also I made sure to actually include "bits.hpp" in my implementation file, and I included <string> in my .hpp file. between all those changes the problem was fixed. No idea which one did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mismatched the return type between the function declaration and its definition. The prototype is:

```
std::string pad_string(std::string s,int total);
```

but the implementation is:

```
void pad_string(std::string s,int total) { ... }
```

The mismatch between the caller and callee could explain why the parameter appeared corrupted at runtime.